# Generate Oracle results to csv

Tags: oracle11g

I'm using coldfusion now to query oracle then save the results to a csv file. It occurred to me that I may be able to print the results directly to csv, but I can't find anything recently written about it except a way to do so using sql developer.  Is there a way to do this in the query ?

Comment: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-write-to-a-csv-file-using-oracle-sql-plus/ or

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I usually do them:

```
 <cfquery name="myQuery"
      datasource="myDatasource">
      <!--- Your query --->
 </cfquery>
 <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=fileanem.csv">
 <!--- Be very careful about line breaks or commas in your data because they'll break the CSV format --->
 <cfsavecontent variable="myData">header1,header2,header3<cfoutput query="myQuery">#Chr(13)##Chr(10)##column1#,#column2#,#column3#</cfoutput></cfsavecontent>
 <cfcontent type="text/csv" variable="#ToBinary(ToBase64(myData.Trim()))#" />
```

Comment: I'm using a java class now. I'll try this to see if it is more effective, it's definitely simpler.

Comment: If you are using sqlplus 12.2, you can just turn on CSV markup.